# Converting point cloud (.txt) to shapefile with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, convert, lidar, xyz

I have lots of .txt  files (point cloud) which are raw data acquired from from LIDAR and containing XYZI values. I want to convert them to shapefile.

Is there a way I can do that instead of adding XY data first and exporting to shapefile one after the other?

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to define what you mean by "point file". There are a number of ways to do this, but most require more familiarity with Python than your question suggests.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense -- a DEM is a raster model, which really ought not be stored in a vector format like shapefile without a great deal of processing.

Comment: It's the raw data acquired from from LIDAR containing XYZI . I need to carry out some processes to generate the raster

Comment: are you familiar with python (arcpy)? this process could be automated easily through the use of a script tool i.e.

Comment: Then describe it as a "point cloud" instead of a DEM. Please put all significant details **in the question**. It's not fair to those who would answer to need to mine the comments for critical information.

Comment: @dru87 yes but I'm not very good with python.  Could you explain better. Thank you

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the .txt file you are working with so we can get a better feel for the dataset?

Comment: Thanks. I have fixed it, although I have a new problem here https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251515/using-python-to-convert-txt-to-shapefile

Comment: @Eniola, please post your answer or delete this post so we can consider this resolved.

Comment: I am voting to close as duplicate because the follow up question have a more complete and accurate code (both in question, from OP) and in the answer in relation to this Q/A. This way, future readers can be directly redirected to updated content.

Answer (score 1):

```
import arcpy

newfcName ="532724.shp"
outpath = r"C:/FLOOD/IKEJA AND KOSOFE"

# Declaration
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace= outpath


# Create new Shapefile and add FIELDS
newfc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfcName, "Point")
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "X", "STRING", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Y", "STRING", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Z", "STRING", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "I", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)

# Reference Cursors
cursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, [ "SHAPE@XY", "X", "Y", "Z", "I"])

# Read File 
a = open("C:/FLOOD/IKEJA AND KOSOFE/DEM/532724.txt","r")
inputF = a.readlines()

for line in inputF:
xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zValue, iValue = line.split(" ")
xy = (float(xCoordinate), float(yCoordinate))
newRow = (xy, str(xCoordinate), str(yCoordinate), str(zValue), float(iValue))
cursor.insertRow(newRow)

a.close()
infc = r"C:/FLOOD/IKEJA AND KOSOFE/532724.shp"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference("Minna UTM Zone 31N")
arcpy.DefineProjection_management(infc, sr)
```